# Should yubikey work for Ubuntu Software installation process?

Tags: ubuntu, yubikey

All from this tutorial is working.

```
https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016649099-Ubuntu-Linux-Login-Guide-U2F
```

But when I am installing programs with Ubuntu software there need authentication for install update or removing package is requiring. When i enter password installation process is running and do not wait for yubikey.

Is that fail or should I add other commands for requiring yubikey?